# onMouseOver function firing before mouseOver

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onmouseover

I am trying to have a div that changes the value of `BarText` when it is hovered over. In my app.js I have the value set like so.

```
const [BarText, setBar] = useState("test")
```

And the values and the function are passed as props to the component where this code is:

```
<NavLink
 to="/sol"
className="systemButton"
onClick={() => {
 setIn(true);}}
onMouseOver={props.setBar('stuff')}
>
```

At the moment, the function is working as it does change the value of the `BarText` from "test" to "stuff", however it does not do it on hover, it seems to do it on render. When I refresh the page the BarText already reads as "Stuff" indicating that the function has already fired.

When I applied several `onMouseOver` events to different divs, the BarText will change to the last one in the component.

It appears that I am not using the `onMouseOver` properly. What error am I making?

Comment: Not something you might find in quick answers, but avoid using `mouseover` `mouseout` Events, unless you really, really know what you're doing. Use instead `mouseenter` `mouseleave`. In JavaSript in general, and in the non reactive React. Actually you might also be interested in Pointer Events as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
onMouseOver={props.setBar('stuff')}
```

to

```
onMouseOver={() => props.setBar('stuff')}
```

Otherwise you are calling the function each time it renders.